# Как интерпретировать сочетание операций "*&"?

Tags: c++, указатели

Изучаю C++. Встретилось следующее: `*&переменная_указатель`.

Я правильно понимаю, что это означает взятие адреса ячейки, на которую указывает указатель? Если так, почему я не могу записать `&(*переменная_указатель)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Вы пометили свой вопрос как C++. В С++ это сочетание нельзя никак конкретно интерпретировать вне детального контекста. Операторы `&` и `*` в С++ - это *перегружаемые* операторы и делать они могут что угодно.
2. Если речь идет именно о *встроенных* унарных операторах `&` и `*`, то пара соседних встроенных операторов `*&` взаимно "аннигилируется", то есть `*&имя_переменной` эквивалентно просто `имя_переменной`.

   О каком "взятии адреса ячейки, на которую указывает указатель" вы ведете речь - не ясно.
3. Почему вы "не можете записать `&(*имя_переменной)`" - это надо у вас спрашивать. Если переменная `имя_переменной` не является указателем, то сделать вы этого не можете просто потому, что встроенный оператор `*` применим только к указателям.

   Пара операторов `&*` тоже "аннигилируется", но для этого нужно (как, впрочем, и в случае `*&`), чтобы само исходное выражение было формально корректным. То есть, например, выражения `&*5` или `*&5` в С++ не являются корректными.

Comment: Дополню примером с перегруженными операторами: `std::unique_ptr<int> x; &*x == x.get();`

Comment: «Аннигиляция» на уровне языка или логики исполнения? Если второе, то это не эквивалетнные записи, т.к. первая это ODR-use, а вторая — нет. Понятно, что в 99.9% это не важно, но всё равно.

Answer (score 4):

Выражение *(&имя_переменной) это взятие адреса переменной и тут же получение значение указателя. Действие бессмысленное, но синтаксически правильное.

Выражение &(*имя_переменной) действие синтаксически НЕ правильное. Так как операция (*имя_переменной) не определена для переменных.

Возможное выражение &(*указатель). Это тоже действие бессмысленное, но синтаксически правильное.

Answer (score 2):

Я могу предположить только один сценарий, где это может пригодится, при передаче аргумента в функцию:

```
#include <iostream>

void resize(int *&_val, int _newSize)
{
    if(_val)
    {
        delete[] _val;
    }

    _val = new int[_newSize];
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *v = nullptr;

    resize(v, 10);

    std::cout << v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Мы передаем нулевой указатель, и функцию должна изменять значение этого указателя. Т.е. значение указателя `v` изменяется после вызова функции `resize`.

Comment: Что это? O_o.  Какое это имеет отношение к заданному вопросу и почему это помечено как "принятый" ответ?

Comment: @AnT, а в чем собственно проблема? Позиция Вашего ответа - сочетание этих операторов бессмысленно. Я привел пример, где это сочетание имеет смысл. Могу привести более "жизненный" пример.

Comment: Во-первых, в вопросе идет речь об "операциях" и, соответственно, *операторах* `&` и `*`. В вашем ответе символы `&` и `*` операторами не являются вообще. Именно поэтому ваш ответ не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. Во-вторых, никакого "сочетание бессмысленно" в моем ответе не постулируется. Где вы такое увидели? Например, применение `&*` к итератору - классическая идиома в С++, в которой нет ничего бессмысленного.